# Sequences of step functions and measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, step-function

I’ve found this result in my Measure Theory teacher’s notes.

> > If $f: \Omega \longrightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ is measurable, then there exists an increasing sequence of step functions $f_n: \Omega \longrightarrow [- \infty , \infty)$ which has $f$ as pointwise limit.

I just can’t manage to find it on the web, and I’m using Zygmund, Measure and Integral as a guide as well, and it says that the sequence might not be increasing. I'm trying to see if this result is right, it just looks very important, but if I can't find it anywhere then there must be some mistake.

**EDIT**: I'm going to add my teacher's proof, so that you can check what he's saying.

For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$, let's consider the partition of [-m,m) given by clopen intervals

$$ A_i=\bigg[-m + \frac{i-1}{2^m}, -m + \frac{i}{2^m} \bigg)$$

for $i=1,...,2m2^m$. We define the increasing sequence of step functions as follows:

$$ f_m(x) =  
\begin{cases} 
      -\infty & f(x)< -m \\
      -m + \frac{i-1}{2^m} & f(x) \in A_i (i=1,...,2m2^m)\\
      m & f(x) \geq m 
   \end{cases}
 $$

It's clear that this sequence's point wise limit is $f$, and if $|f(x)| < M \ \ \ \forall x$, then convergence is uniform.

Comment: What is your definition of step function? In my mind, a step function is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{R_i}$ where $R_i$s are intervals. But these $f_m$s cannot match with my definition in general.